# RSS Feeds - Are they Cached?

Tags: rss

How can I (or is it possible) to remove some blog posts out of a feed such as Google Feedburner?  I have removed some from my blog but obviously looks like they are cached somehow.  I just don't want some of the blog posts to be able to be read through anyone who subscribes...I don't want them to see those posts that I removed in the future in the feed itself.

Am I asking the impossible here?  I don't know how RSS works in terms of cache/history.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot do that. It is based on the ATOM protocol that doesn't support updates of the achieved feeds (once the change is picked up by feed burner). You will be able to update the post before it is cached. If the user clicks on the feed and is redirected to the actual post itself, he/she will see the latest version.